# React Native - getting error when running command "react-native unlink"

Tags: react-native, react-native-linking

After upgrading past react-native 0.60.....Im being warned that I should unlink all the 3rd party libraries that were linked manually (as RN now takes care of it via auto-linking).

However when I run `react-native unlink <depedency>` I get the error `Something went wrong while unlinking. Reason Expected [\n\r] but end of input found`

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is one of the files parsed by the unlinking tool doesn't end with an empty newline.

Comment: Dont think its related to the library its unlinking....same thing happens with every single library that I unlink

Comment: I know it will sound silly but, sometimes i forget to unlink before removing a package, then i have to reinstall it, manually link it or whatnot, and after that i unlink first, check if there is some changes in files that normally would have, and remove the package;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reason is, that in one of your files, the blanc-line at the end of the file is missing.

Please check following files for this empty line:

- ios/[Project].xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
- android/settings.gradle

You also might unlink your modules manually like this:

Open `android/settings.gradle`, remove the include & project Lines

After cleanup, the file should look like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'MyBeautifullApp'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```

Comment: where we can get this file ios/[Project].xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Answer (score 0):

use this command => React-native Unintsall "package-name"

Answer (score 0):

I hope it would help you out:

If you're removing a global package however, any applications referencing it will crash.

Here are different options:

npm uninstall  removes the module from node_modules, but not package.json

npm uninstall  --save also removes it from dependencies in package.json

npm uninstall  --save-dev also removes it from devDependencies in package.json

npm -g uninstall  --save also removes it globally